# Canonical isomorphism from $\Lambda^{(p,q)} (V \otimes \mathbb{C})$ to $\Lambda^{p+q} (V \otimes \mathbb{C})$

Tags: differential-forms, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, almost-complex

I'm having trouble understanding this 'natural' isomorphism when discussing complex differential forms. Let $(M, J)$ be an almost complex manifold. Then its complexified cotangent bundle decomposes as $(T^* M \otimes \mathbb{C}) = T^*M^{(1,0)} \oplus T^*M^{(0,1)}$. Therefore its exterior algebra also decomposes into $\Lambda^k (T^* M \otimes \mathbb{C}) = \bigoplus_{p+q=k} \Lambda^p(T^* M^{(1,0)}) \otimes \Lambda^q(T^* M^{(0,1)}) =: \bigoplus_{p+q=k} \Lambda^{(p,q)} (T^* M \otimes \mathbb{C})$. Let $v^I$ be a basis for $\Lambda^p(T^* M^{(1,0)})$ and $w^J$ basis for $\Lambda^q(T^* M^{(0,1)})$, then

$$
\eta = \sum_{|I| = p, |J| = q} a_{IJ} v^I \otimes w^J \in \Lambda^{(p,q)}(T^* M \otimes \mathbb{C}).
$$

This is all (somewhat) understandable. I have trouble with the following identification;

$$
\eta \mapsto \sum_{|I| = p, |J| = q} a_{IJ} v^I \wedge w^J \in \Lambda^{p+q}(T^* M \otimes \mathbb{C}),
$$

is supposed to be a canonical isomorphism (onto its image). To me it looks like we just applied $Alt$ to $\eta$. In what way is this an isomorphism, or why can we identify element of $\Lambda^{(p,q)}(T^* M \otimes \mathbb{C})$ with an element in $\Lambda^{p+q}(T^* M \otimes \mathbb{C})$. They just look like different objects to me.

Comment: The point is that the very first isomorphism (decomposition) is making that identification. No one writes $\Lambda^p(T^{*1,0})\wedge\Lambda^q(T^{*0,1})$, but obviously we're talking about a subspace of a fully skew-symmetric vector space of tensors. Because the two spaces $\Lambda^p(T^{*1,0})$ and $\Lambda^q(T^{*0,1})$ intersect only in $0$ and are already skew-symmetric themselves, the bilinear mapping sending $(\eta,\xi)$ to $\eta\wedge\xi$ is indeed an isomorphism.